# e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdi

Tags: fsck

I have a WD Mybook Live disk which stopped working one day.
I took our the HD and connected it to my Linux box to try and rescue the data but so far without success.

### The fdisk shows the below:

```
Disk /dev/sdi: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Generic         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: <XXXXXXXXXXX>

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdi1  1032192    5031935    3999744  1.9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdi2  5031936    9031679    3999744  1.9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdi3    30720    1032191    1001472  489M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdi4  9031680 3907028991 3897997312  1.8T Microsoft basic data
```

### But I can't mount the disk. Running e2fsck I get the following:

```
sudo e2fsck -n /dev/sdi
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdi

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdi
```

### Reading in another post I tried to fix this by copying the superblock from one of the other copies, but with no success.

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdi4 
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sdi4 contains a ext4 file system
    last mounted on /CacheVolume on Wed Oct 17 21:04:47 2018
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 487249664 4k blocks and 121815040 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 820e42ab-4109-4dde-8ad9-545c825e5e52
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848
```

```
sudo  e2fsck -b 20480000 /dev/sdi4 
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdi4

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

/dev/sdi4 contains a ext4 file system
    last mounted on /CacheVolume on Wed Oct 17 21:04:47 2018
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You could try a rescue program like [GNU Drescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html).

Comment: It looks like some interesting RAID configuration on the drive itself.  It might be something they do for protection to keep people from pulling the drive and using it in something else.  Is it just not reading if you plug it back into the enclosure?  Also, what is the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`?  It might show something about that RAID.

Comment: thanks @Terrance. mdstat does not show anything interesting :
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
However it is probably because I am mounting the drive externally through a USB enclosure after pulling it out of the original WD mybook live.
When the disk was in the original enclosure, the UI would get stuck and I could not access the data on the drive. Not sure why.

Comment: `e2fsck` doesn't work on devices like /dev/sdi, it works on ext2/3/4 partitions like /dev/sdix, but your two data partitions don't appear to be ext2/3/4... unless you look at your image where it says "/dev/sdi4 contains a ext4 file system". So what is it? Tell us more about where this disk came from, and what OS you were running on it. Maybe better to reinstall the drive into the original system and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: The HD is a disk I took out of a WesternDigital Mybook Live NAS, after it stopped working.  Not sure what was installed on it before...